# Windows Print Pictures change placement?

Tags: windows, windows-10, printing, printer

[image: Image Example]
I use this 4-in-1-page print mode A LOT.
But new printer prints from the right side instead of the left, so can't feed it half a piece of letter-sized paper anymore without using a different print program like acrobat.

Anyway to get windows Print Pictures to change the default location to one of the marked X's?

Comment: This is normally a setting in the printer itself - Look in the printer documentation and try to set to your requirements.  You can also check the Windows Printer driver setup as well.

Comment: My first thought as well. But I've never seen this setting in any of the printer driver/setup software from Epson to HP to Canon.

Comment: Take a look through this HP article below. It addresses some page orientation settings as well as default settings. 

https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-laserjet-mfp-m436-printer-series/11596606/document/c05303777

Answer (score 0):

Many printers can rotate the orientation 180 degrees. Go to printer settings via *options* (see screenshot). You can find the device-specific setting in the documentation of your printer.

[image: print dialog options]